# Difference between Identity Server 4 and Identity Server 5

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, identityserver5

I am currently trying to research differences between the IS4 and IS5 but finding it hard to get a solid comparison of the two.
Does anyone have any good reasons why someone should upgrade from 4 to 5, and are there any drawbacks to upgrading?

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Version 4 will have end of support at the end of 2022, so I would recommend that you use version 5 for all new projects. Version 5.0 is basically a clone of version with some new features. So upgrading from version 4 to version 5 is very easy.

The only thing to look out for is the licensing model for version 5.

the picture below shows the relationships between the different editions:

[image]

Today you should of course be using version 6.x instead.